# How to do Spring rest template call with service request as a input parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest, templates

This is the input parameter,

```
> <ServiceRequest>
>      <filters>
>           <Criteria field="launchedDate" operator="GREATER">2019-08-18</Criteria>
>     </filters> </ServiceRequest>
```

I am using below CURL:

```
curl -u "uname:pass" -H "X-Requested-With: Curl" -X "POST" "https://qualysapi.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/qps/rest/3.0/search/was/wasscan/" > was_finding.txt
```

How to do the same in the spring rest template?